# iPhone app not running on simulator xcode

Tags: iphone, swift

So I'm trying to run a new tabbed application in the iPhone simulator, but I keep getting a black screen after my app loading screen.

I've tried Reset Content and Settings and I've made sure that my storyboard is the main interface.

My app also doesn't appear in the iPhone simulator app pages

Comment: You should post your code, especially viewDidLoad and methods of that nature.

Comment: I just added labels to first and second view after creating a tabbed storyboard, I haven't changed anything else

Answer (score 1):

Black screen appear only when, you do not set any initial launching screen in the application, and thus it show black window screen. In your storyboard select "Tab Bar controller Scene" and check its attribute inspector and check if "is Initial View controller" field is selected or not.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your initial view  correctly in Storyboard

[image]